# Is there a javascript equivalent to using @media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 570px) {

    #header {
        .flex-wrap(wrap);
        .justify-content(center);

        #headerTitles {
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 571px) and (max-width: 950px) {

    #header.authenticated {
        .flex-wrap(wrap);
        .justify-content(center);

        #headerTitles {
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way that I can use Javascript (not jQuery) to dynamically add or remove a class to the  to represent the two different sizes and then recode this something like:

```
.small #headerTitles { margin-top: 1rem; }
.large #headerTitles { margin-top: 2rem; }
```

If this works then can someone comment as to if using Javascript is a better way to do this?

Comment: yes, you can, use jQuery addClass() ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I am looking for a javascript (not jQuery) way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ [`.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Answer (score 86):

You can use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for media queries in javascript.

for example

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 570px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at less than 570px
}
else {
    // window width is greater than 570px
}
```

Please refer the below links for better understanding

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

**Updated as per comment**

Please refer the plunker: "http://plnkr.co/edit/wAKFEFz0NU6ZaEmywlgc?p=preview"

For better understanding: "http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/matchmediamultiple.shtml"

For web browser support information: 
"https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/"

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you give an example with say for example the width of a <div> is set to 100px when the window is less than 500 px and 150px when the window is less than 600 px. Would this be able to change the width of the <div> dynamically as I resize the window. Also is this something that would work on all modern browsers?

Comment: @SamanthaJ : Updated the answer!!