# If window.width hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html and i have also a carousel with pictures. But on small devices they don't look good. So my question is how can i hide the div if the width is less than 1015px? Here is my `div`:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="myCarousel"  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 </body>
</html>
```

I know already that i have to use javascript or css. But it didn't work for me. So can someone tell me which javascript i have to use for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511001/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-to-using-media-query/31511072#31511072

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then simply use hidden-xs class on div which you want to hide.

Comment: that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1015px) {
   #myCarousel{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: `hidden-xs` will do this automatically. no need to do this.

Comment: hidden-xs hides the div on screen width < 768px by default. He wants 1015.

Comment: _But on small devices_ **small devices** which have the width < 1015.

Comment: Friend, in this line of work we work with pixel and em, not Android TV or AppleWatch.