# function based on screen size

Tags: javascript, media-queries

onClick on button pops up a registration form. the problem is that I need to do it only when the screen size is 1440px and more.

```
   <a href="#" class="button"onmousedown="viewForm()">start</a>

   function viewForm(){
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
    };
```

Comment: What happens when the screen size is less than 1440px?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

Comment: Do you want the screen width or the browser viewport width? Seems like you'd want the browser viewport width

Comment: you either need to provide further detail, or your question is most probably a duplicate of either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511001/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-to-using-media-query). on the off-chance that you just want to utilize your css breakpoints in css, then [this link](https://github.com/AllThingsSmitty/css-breakpoints-in-js) should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
function viewForm(){
  if (window.innerWidth >= 1440) {
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

Be aware that if a user decrease the size of the window you form will remain visible even below 1440. You might want to check for the `resize` event as well.

You can update the function above this way:

```
function viewForm(){
  if (window.innerWidth > 1440) {
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
  }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', viewForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event.Try resizing your window you will see the other element visible.Hope it helps.

```js
function reportWindowSize() {
  console.log(window.innerWidth)
  if (window.innerWidth >= 1440) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
  }
  // just for test my pc has small screen
  else if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
    document.getElementById("b").style.display = "block"
  }
}

function viewForm() {
  document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
};

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

```html
<a href="#" id="a" class="button" onmousedown="viewForm()" style="display:none">start</a>

<a href="#" id="b" class="button" onmousedown="viewForm()" style="display:none">ENDIT</a>

<form id="form"><input type="text"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read window size in several ways (take a look here [Device and Viewport Size In JavaScript](https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/)

So something like this should work:

```
<a href="#" class="button"onmousedown="viewForm()">start</a>

function viewForm(){
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1440 ) {
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Maybe you don't need all that, you may simply hide the link with a CSS media query, all depends on what you are trying to do.