# Jquery multiple condition in window width similar to media query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to check, I am trying to add a window width condition in my function, Is this the best way to do it? So this is similar to a media query, in the sense of Min width and Max width

```
if ($(window).width() <= 440 && $(window).width() <=768) {
// Do something
}
```

Comment: window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight are what you are probably looking for. 
These questions have more info: [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) and [What is the difference between window.innerWidth and screen.width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443482/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-and-screen-width)

Comment: What is the best way? It depends on the task. What is the problem you face? I can tell you doing `$(window).width()` multiple times is not the best way.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I assume you run the code on resize?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511001/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-to-using-media-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Less than 440 AND less than 768 doesn't make sense. You probably wanted greater than 440 less than 768.

**2.** You should wrap it around window resize to trigger the action on window resize.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
if ($(window).width() >= 440 && $(window).width() <=600) {
$(".content").html("Between 440 and 600");
}
else if($(window).width()> 600) {
$(".content").html("Bigger than 600");
}
else if($(window).width()< 440) {
$(".content").html("Smaller than 440");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Resize the window</div>
```