# How to run javascript file only on certain media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

on my website i have an p5.js sketch displayed in the background. the sketch is linked in an seperate file in the head section of my html file. the problem is, that i have a second sketch only for the mobile media query of the website. therefore i tried to add following if statement around my sketch in the file:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 600) {
// my p5.js sketch
}
```

somehow thats not working for safari browser...

is there an other way to hide a script file on a website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a javascript equivalent to using @media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511001/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-to-using-media-query)

Answer (score 0):

There is [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method in JavaScript which is also supported almost on all browsers. Here's an example.

```
function checkMedia(media) {
    if (media.matches) {
        // Mobile
    } else {
        // Desktop
    }
}

var m = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
checkMedia(m); // Call listener function at run time
m.addListener(checkMedia); // Attach listener function on state changes
```